# How to read Process Histories

Tags: core-service

Can we access Process Histories using Core Service API? If yes which filter we have to use? ProcessesFilterData?

If there is no core service API, then which table in the database will have this information so that I can write a custom code to retrieve the process histories information?

Appreciate your inputs.

Thanks
Vijay.

Answer (score 5):

The CME uses Core Service, so if you can see something in the CME you can definitely get that information from Core Service directly (assuming you are on 2013 or later, but this is also mostly true for 2011 as well I understand). You should try to avoid going directly to the Content Manager database for information, as the structure of the database is not a public API and could change between versions (or even hotfixes) making your code invalid.

In the case of Workflow Process Histories you do indeed use the `ProcessesFilterData`. This is a subclass of `SystemWideListFilterData`, and so you use it in conjunction with the Core Service client's `GetSystemWideList` or `GetSystemWideListXml` methods, as follows:

```
var processesFilter = new ProcessesFilterData {
    ProcessType = ProcessType.Historical
};
var processes = client.GetSystemWideList(processesFilter);

foreach (var identifiableObject in processes)
{
    var processInstance = (ProcessHistoryData) client.Read(identifiableObject.Id, null);
    // do something with your Process History object here
}
```

Comment: Thanks David. I thought ProcessFilterData will only get data from publishing queue. I will try this and check if I get the information from process histories using this filter.

Comment: I don't see parameters for passing a publication ID and date range. How can we filter the process history for a specific publication within a date range?

Comment: I'm getting this error after executing above piece of code..ErrorUnable to cast object of type 'Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.ProcessInstanceData' to type 'Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.ProcessHistoryData'.

Comment: I expect you can filter by Publication by using the filter's ForRepository property. I don't see anything for specifying date ranges - You'll have to do that as part of your loop or similar.

Comment: I expect you're getting the cast error if you've removed the ProcessType = ProcessType.Historical clause. As per the Core Service documentation, "ProcessType gets or sets the ProcessType condition to constrain the items returned by the list to this value. Using this condition it is possible to return only Process Instance objects, only Process History objects, or both, which is the default" If you want to return both you'll need to cast the objects to the parent ProcessData class

Comment: David, ForRepository property is not available in ProcessesFilterData class. we are using 2011 version. IS this property not available in 2011 version?........... Also could you please met know where can I find API documentation on "Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.ProcessInstanceData" and  "Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.ProcessHistoryData" classes? I searched in the tridion site but not able to get it.

Comment: Ah, didn;t realise you were on 2011. Looks like that property may have been added afterwards. In that case, as with your date range, you'll have to filter yourself after getting the results. Documentation available at https://www.sdltridionworld.com/downloads/documentation/SDLTridion2011SP1/index.aspx (login to SDL Tridion World needed)